# Bracha over Nazir or Metzora shaving their hair

Tags: blessing, tractate-brachot, hair, tzaraas-negaim, nozir

Was a bracha historically made over shaving the heads/bodies of nazirim or metzoraim?

If so what was the girsa?

Comment: It might be different in the 2 cases as for the Nazir it is part of another mitzvah (are there b'rachot on brining sacrifices?) https://outorah.org/p/6385/

Comment: Right thank you. And yes many rishonim hold that there were Brachot for korbanot in zman bait sheni but I wonder if that extended to the above practices